# jQuery ui datepicker img only showing on homepage

Tags: css, jquery-ui, relative-path, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using a reservation widget running with the jQuery ui.

http://www.hearthstoneresort.com/

When you view the home page, the calendar buttons beside arrival and departure show up fine, but if you go to any other page they don't load.

I'm aware that this is due to the the images using relative path, but I need to somehow alter the jQuery so that it uses absolute path, this way it would load them as "/ew_images/Calendar.png" instead of "ew_images/Calendar.png" .. unsure how to do this.

I've posted a pastebin with the jquery ui code.. help is appreciated.

http://pastebin.com/yViwjagz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually fixed this by setting the base href to the root of my website. :)

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp